# Combine obserables rxjs 5.5+

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

Consider the following code that getting an entity and load the relevant model for each ID property (Load the foreign keys objects) :

```
if (!lazyLoad) {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.endpoint}/file`, {
          params: params
        }).pipe(
          mergeMap(res => this.loadModel(res, 'prop1ID')),
          mergeMap(res => this.loadModel(res, 'prop2ID')),
          mergeMap(res => this.loadModel(res, 'prop2ID'))
        )
      }
}
```

the first merge working, the second get `undefind`.
tried to read about `merge` and `mergeAll` with no success.

the object from `http` request looks like:

```
{
        id: '1',
        name: 'user',
        prop1ID: 34,
        prop2ID: 44,
        prop3ID: 54
}
```

After those 3 actions i want it to look like (with help of `loadModel()` function):

```
{
        id: '1',
        name: 'user',
        prop1ID: 34,
        prop1IDModel: { ... },
        prop2ID: 44,
        prop2IDModel: { ... },
        prop3ID: 54
        prop3IDModel: { ... },
}
```

My `loadModel` function:

```
private loadModel(entity, modelProperty): Observable<object> {
    switch (modelProperty) {
      case 'prop1ID':
          this.generalService.getProp1ID(entity.prop1ID).subscribe((data) => {
            entity.prop1IDModel = data;
            return of(entity);
          });
        break;
      case 'prop2ID':
        ...
        break;
      case 'prop3ID':
        ...
        break;
      default:
        return of(entity);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure `this.loadModel` returns anything?

Comment: @martin you right i will post what i have in loadModel

Comment: Well you're not retuning anything in `case 'prop1ID'` for example.

Comment: @martin `return of(entity);`

Comment: You can not return an asynchronous value from a synchronous function. Consider returning a `Promise` from `loadModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement doesn’t actually return an Observable—with the `return` statement inside the subscription, you’ll always reach the `break` statement before returning anything if the Observable involves an asynchronous task.

I’d refactor loadModel() to return an Observable as @martin suggested:

```
private loadModel(entity, modelProperty): Observable<object> {
    switch (modelProperty) {
      case 'prop1ID':
          return this.generalService.getProp1ID(entity.prop1ID)
          .mergeMap((data) => {
            entity.prop1IDModel = data;
            return Observable.of(entity);
          });
        break;
        // etc.
```